# What is the correct way to define types for Redux actions?

Tags: redux, flowtype

I have an application that is using Redux for state management, and I'm trying to add Flow type annotations.

I've created a very simple test case here that outlines the issue I'm running into.

I've created a union `Action` type, and then within a reducer function, I'm using `switch` to make decisions about what state to return based on the action's `type` property. Within each case of the switch statement, I'm accessing different properties on my `action` parameter.

I don't understand why Flow is telling me it can't find certain properties on the `action` argument. Everything appears to be defined properly, and I really can't see anything that is wrong here.

Here's my test case:

https://flowtype.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHZQLxQFBSgHygG8pRIAuKAcgDEBJAJQGUAVKgGigBMBDYHygHkARgCsICKAF9cBYqXARKVJgFEAwoIByAEQ5REwCAFs6XSgGdgAJ0SoA5tOzYy0JvyOZisgDaIrlDDW1jwgADwi4ggAfOzYMtgAZgCuqAgo6NYQXMlwEAAUVnxKUO7FnDzpaIFVqACUlKjJxsIQ1t54FgDuhnAAFlD5lUhoAHSudR14UHA8FtC0jKxUlESy01BZwMnW6EVGo35Wo4l2XHSoXBAAHvmGJpjRBkbGo4hcmBhYwxmjvPxvLh1ADc6ycG1m82oak0uhWUw2Wx2ew8EEO-mAJzOFyut3uxkezxMgM+31qbxeZhBYJkGyuiR4yR8wHIYLwSN2UAADKC8DIpEA

I thought that *maybe* the issue was related to using the `switch` statement, so here's a version using `if`, with the same issues:

https://flowtype.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHZQLxQFBSgHygG8pRIAuKAcgDEBJAJQGUAVKgGigBMBDYHygHkARgCsICKAF9cBYqXARKVJgFEAwoIByAEQ5REwCAFs6XSgGdgAJ0SoA5tOzYy0JvyOZisgDaIrlDDW1jwgADwi4ggAfOzYMtgAZgCuqAgo6NYQXMlwEAAUVnxKUO7FnDzpaIFVqACUlKjJxsIQ1t54iIlQ+ZVIaAB0rpgYWLSMrFR1HXhQWcDJ1uhFRgN+VgOJdlx0qFwQAB75hiaY0QZGxgOIXCNYfRkDvPzXXHUA3LIyeLJdPQ+DYajMZqTS6KYzPDzRbLDwQNb+YCbba7fZHE7GM4XEyvO5QAGoa6XMwfL6yWTQpZQAAMnykQA

Comment: Having no idea what flow does, your reducers look fine if that is indeed what the action is suppose to be sending. Is flow somehow using redux  here or are you just testing what you think redux is doing?

Comment: The two things are separate, I'm just trying to add Flow type annotations to my Redux actions and reducers.

Comment: Got it. Not sure what you mean with the last edit though - why would you expect that to be an error?

Comment: Er, yeah, you're right, that's not going to be an error, I made a mistake. I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please note that your `reduce` function is not a valid reducer. A redux reducer must have the following signature

```
(state: State, action: Action) => State
```

Flow is pessimistic about refinements (theoretically you could change the `action.data` reference in the callback). A way to help Flow keep a refinement is to use a const binding ([docs](https://flowtype.org/docs/dynamic-type-tests.html#caveats))

```
function reduce(state: State, action: Action): number {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FIRST': 
      const data = action.data;
      return state.list.findIndex(item => item.id === data.id);
    case 'SECOND': 
      const itemId = action.itemId
      return state.list.findIndex(item => item.id === itemId);
    default:
      return 0;
  }
}
```

or, IMO even better, split the cases into several helper functions

```
function findIndex(state: State, id): number {
  return state.list.findIndex(item => item.id === id);
}

function reduce(state: State, action: Action): number {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FIRST': 
      return findIndex(state, action.data.id)
    case 'SECOND': 
      return findIndex(state, action.itemId)
    default:
      return 0;
  }
}
```

Also, you can find an example of a flow-typed app in the redux repo (see examples/todos-flow)

Comment: How to use constants instead of strings? It's stupid